# How can I have section 100 and section 100a

Tags: sectioning, numbering

So I'm typesetting a document, and I go through entries 0 to 99 without trouble, then discover this person has sections 100a and 100. Well, I can get two section 100s easily enough by adding `\setcounter{section}{99}` after the first section 100, but how do I add section 100a without screwing up the other 150 section in the document?

So to be clear, the structure is:

```
0
1
2
...
98
99
100a
100
101
...
151
```

Edit with additional details: I'm using the article class, as I've never figured out what the others are for, and am indeed using `hyperref`.

Comment: Are you using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) as well? What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: @Werner Damn, should have put in an example: article (all I ever use) and yes.

Comment: And of course, I go to the source document and discover the version I was using has a mistake and it should be 100a and 100b after all. Ah well, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Stretching a bit the syntax, we can define `\section+{title}` to add a letter to the previous section number. I exploit the fact that `\alph{secondary}` expands to nothing when the `secondary` counter has value zero.

In the example I use `hyperref`, which is not needed. Just add the code *after* loading `hyperref`, if wanted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref,bookmark}

\let\latexsection\section
\newif\ifsecondary
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s}
 {%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\latexsection*}{\newsection}%
 }

\newcounter{secondary}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\thesection\expandafter
    {\thesection\alph{secondary}}%
  \ifdefined\theHsection % to keep hyperref happy
    \let\theHsection\thesection
  \fi
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\newsection}{t+ o m}
 {%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\global\secondarytrue}
    {\global\secondaryfalse
     \ifnum\value{secondary}=0 \else
       \setcounter{secondary}{0}%
     \fi}
  \ifsecondary
    \addtocounter{section}{-1}%
    \stepcounter{secondary}%
  \fi
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\latexsection{#3}}{\latexsection[#2]{#3}}%
 }

\begin{document}

\section{Should be one}\label{one}

\section*{No number}

\section{Should be two}\label{two}
\section+{Should be two-a}\label{two-a}
\section+{Should be two-b}\label{two-b}

\section{Should be three}\label{three}

References: \ref{one}, \ref{two}, \ref{two-a}, \ref{two-b}, \ref{three}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you need to have the secondary section before the normal one (although this doesn't make any sense), here's a way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref,bookmark}

\let\latexsection\section
\newif\ifsecondary
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s}
 {%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\latexsection*}{\newsection}%
 }

\newcounter{secondary}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\thesection\expandafter
    {\thesection\alph{secondary}}%
  \ifdefined\theHsection
    \let\theHsection\thesection
  \fi
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\newsection}{t+ o m}
 {%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\global\secondarytrue}
    {\global\secondaryfalse
     \ifnum\value{secondary}=0 \else
       \setcounter{secondary}{0}%
     \fi}
  \ifsecondary
    \stepcounter{secondary}%
  \fi
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\latexsection{#3}}{\latexsection[#2]{#3}}%
  \ifsecondary
    \addtocounter{section}{-1}%
  \fi
 }

\begin{document}

\section{Should be one}\label{one}

\section*{No number}

\section{Should be two}\label{two}
\section+{Should be three-a}\label{three-a}
\section+{Should be three-b}\label{three-b}

\section{Should be three}\label{three}

References: \ref{one}, \ref{two}, \ref{three-a}, \ref{three-b}, \ref{three}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And it turns out the first example is in fact what I need, with a little modification. Thank you.

Comment: And by a little modification, I meant one line, in the 2nd version of the program. This took me 44 minutes to figure out.

Answer (score 15):

Instead of setting the counter to `100`, I would start by adding `-1` after the special section so that it works after moving around (it may end up as 75a after all).

You can simply re-define `\thesection` which seems to be setup as `\arabic{section}`.

If you re-define it with

```
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}a}
```

you get an `a` after the number. To be independent of the `\arabic` part (it could be also Roman numbering), you can do

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\thesection\expandafter{\thesection a}
```

or with [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)

```
\appto\thesection{a}
```

---

Doing this in a group saves you from restoring the initial value (which may also be done with a few `\let`s).

---

A command that works with all counters can be defined as

```
\newcommand*{\addToTheCounter}[2]{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\csname the#1%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname the#1\endcsname#2}}
```

or with `etoolbox`

```
\newcommand*{\addToTheCounter}[2]{\csappto{the#1}{#2}}
```

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,hyperref,etoolbox}
\newcommand*{\addToTheCounter}[2]{%
  \csappto{the#1}{#2}%
  \csappto{theH#1}{#2}} % for hyperref
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{section}{8}
\section{9}
\lipsum[2]
{
  \addToTheCounter{section}{a}
  \section{10a}\label{weird}
} \addtocounter{section}{-1}
\lipsum[2]
\section{10}\label{weird2}
\lipsum[2]

see \ref{weird} and \ref{weird2}
\section{11}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 14):

`\thesection` can be redefined appropriately:

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{%
  \ifnum\value{section}<102 %
    \the\numexpr\value{section}-1\relax
  \else
    \ifnum\value{section}=102 %
      100a%
    \else
      \the\numexpr\value{section}-2\relax
    \fi
  \fi
}

% Increase the space for the section number in the table of contents
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newlength\tocnumwidth
\settowidth{\tocnumwidth}{\textbf{100a} }
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname l@section\endcsname{1.5em}{\tocnumwidth}{}{}

\usepackage[colorlinks,bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}% for testing

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\bigskip
\hrule

\section{First section}\label{first}
\section{Next section}\label{next}

\section*{\dots}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\dots}
\setcounter{section}{99}

\section{Luftballons}\label{99}
\section{Lorem}\label{lorem}
\section{Ipsum}\label{ipsum}
\section{Dolor}\label{dolor}
\hrule
\bigskip

Reference list: \ref{first}, \ref{next}, \dots,
  \ref{99}, \ref{lorem}, \ref{ipsum}, \ref{dolor}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

Just for comparison here are a few ways of achieving this with ConTeXt. I have set the special section to be 3 rather than 100. All of these ensure that the numbering will work for references and table of contents.

### Define custom conversion

If this is something that only needs to be done for sections whose number is already known, then you can define a custom conversion; the easiest way to do that is using Lua.

```
\startluacode
  commands.weirdcounter = function (number, offset) 
    if number < offset then
      context("%s", number)
    elseif number == offset then
      context("%sa", offset)
    else
      context("%s", number - 1)
    end
  end
\stopluacode

\define[1]\weirdcounter{\ctxcommand{weirdcounter(#1,3)}}

\defineconversion[weirdnumbering][\weirdcounter]

\setuphead[section][conversion=weirdnumbering]

\setupinteraction[state=start]

\starttext

\placecontent

\dorecurse{5}
  {\expanded{\section{Section \recurselevel}}}

\stoptext
```

### Use a coupled heading command with `ownnumber`

For a one off use, you can define a new section head, say `ownsection` that is coupled with `section` (so that you inherit style etc), but allows you to set the section number. For example:

```
\setuphead[section][conversion=weirdnumbering]

\definehead[ownsection][section][ownnumber=yes]

\setupinteraction[state=start]

\starttext

\placecontent

\section{One}
\section{Two}
\ownsection{3a}{Three}
\section{Four}
\section{Five}

\stoptext
```