# How can I make a command like \tag, but for chapter numbering?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, chapters

The `\tag` command from `amsmath` allows one to provide a custom label for an equation that's used for all references to that equation ([example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12035/)). I'm T<sub>E</sub>Xing a book whose chapters are numbered 1, ∞, 2, 3,…, so it would be convenient to define a `\chaptertag` command and use it like this:

```
% what I'm hoping to do
\documentclass{amsbook}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{thm}[equation]{Theorem}
% I don't know how to do this
\newcommand{\chaptertag}[1]{ ... }

\begin{document}

\chapter{Integration}
\chaptertag{\ensuremath{\infty}}

\section{Stokes' theorem}
\begin{thm}[Stokes]
If $M$ is a compact, smooth manifold-with-boundary and $\omega \in
\Omega^{n-1}(M)$, then
\begin{equation}
\int_M d\omega = \int_{\partial M} \omega.
\end{equation}
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Here's the hoped-for output:

[image]

I know there are other ways to do this (I produced the above screenshot with a variant of `\fnsymbol`), but I'm interested in a `\tag`-like command because it makes it easier to reorder chapters.

In summary, **how can I define a `\chaptertag` command that behaves like `\tag`, but for chapter numbering?**

Comment: You could build off [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129134/8528).

Comment: @jon: I looked at that answer, but I couldn't figure out how to make it independent of the number I wanted to modify.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One needs to redefine both `\thechapter` and `\thesection` immediately before the chapter in question, and one needs to revert to the default definitions immediately before the next chapter. If you have more than one chapter with special "numbering", it's advisable to define macros -- called `\specialform` and `\defaultform` in the example below -- that collect the macros related to the re-definitions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{thm}[equation]{Theorem}

\newcommand\specialform[1]{%
   \let\savechapter\thechapter
   \renewcommand\thechapter{#1}
   \let\savesection\thesection
   \renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
   \addtocounter{chapter}{-1}}
\newcommand\defaultform{%
   %% revert to original forms
   \renewcommand\thechapter{\savechapter}
   \renewcommand\thesection{\savesection}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{In the beginning}
\dots

\specialform{$\infty$}

\chapter{Integration}     \label{ch:int}
\section{Stokes' Theorem} \label{sec:stokes}
\begin{thm}[Stokes]       \label{thm:stokes}
If $M$ is a compact, smooth manifold-with-boundary and $\omega \in
\Omega^{n-1}(M)$, then
\begin{equation}          \label{eq:omega}
\int_M d\omega = \int_{\partial M} \omega.
\end{equation}
\end{thm}

Chapter \ref{ch:int}, section \ref{sec:stokes}, theorem \ref{thm:stokes}, equation \eqref{eq:omega}


\defaultform

\chapter{Next}
\section{Pythagoras}
\begin{thm}[Pythagoras]
We have 
\begin{equation} \label{eq:pyth}
a^2+b^2=c^2\,.
\end{equation}
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @ArunDebray - If this answer has been helpful, feel free to upvote and/or "accept" it. ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't see your comment! I should know better. Answer is accepted.